# osm2pgsql failed import The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osm2pgrouting

I got error message, when loading osm file to PostgreSQL by osm2pgsql command. I run the following command line :

```
osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres --hstore -S D:\osm2pgsql\default.style  -U postgres -W mypassword -d osm -r "D:\.....roads.osm"
```

and i got this error message:

```
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Open failed for 'mypassword': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised in the [doc](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md), you can get a full list of options using `osm2pgsql -h -v`

- you have specified twice the `-U postgres` parameter
- `-W` is a password prompt. The alternative (without `-W`) is to save the password in the `PGPASS` environment
- `-r` should take a parameter or be removed (same as  `-r auto`)
- the input file(s) is specified without a parameter name. Since the `-W` (password prompt) is not expected to be followed by a value, the found value is interpreted as an input file name and triggers the error.